# Use a static type only obtainable at runtime

Tags: java, inheritance, instanceof, dynamic-cast, static-typing

Let's say I have a situation as follows:

A class `X` has a field `s`  of type `S`.

`S` is extended by two classes `A` and `B` both implementing some same methods/fields that we all know should then be implemented in `S` but, unfortunately, this is not the case.

Now I want to do something like this:

```
"A or B" downcast_field;
if(s instanceof A)
    downcast_field = (A)s;
else if (s instanceof B)
     downcast_field = (B)s;

//do something common for the two cases but that need methods implemented both in A and B
```

The problem is then having in advance a static type (out of the `IFs`) that allows me to call such methods.

I guess that due to bad design this is actually impossible and I have to write twice the same code, which is ugly, but perhaps there is a solution that I am not seeing right now.

Comment: Can you add an interface to `A` and `B`?

Comment: The design is very bad man! You need to change it

Comment: @pratik I would have already done that if possible! Unfortunately it has to stay like this for the moment

Comment: Which class are you using the above code in? Ideally A Or B can be represented using S itself

Comment: In class X, and the field is of type S.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Let's suppose I can add interface for the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can change `A` and `B`, then you can add the same interface to both. That would allow you to give this type to `downcast_field` and invoke methods.

If you can't change `A` and `B`, then you have two options:

- You can write `A2` and `B2`. Copy the code from `A` and `B` into the new types. That allows you to modify the code (unless you can't control the creation of those types). Alternatively, you could also now create `S2` which extends `S` and put the common code in there and then extend `A2`/`B2` from that.
- Create an interface and then two implementations which just delegate the calls to the real type.

  In this solution, you can

  ```
  Wrapper downcast_field;
  if(s instanceof A)
      downcast_field = new AWrapper( (A)s );
  else if (s instanceof B)
      downcast_field = new BWrapper( (B)s );

  downcast_field.foo();
  ```

  You can make the two wrappers extend the same type and move common code there.

Comment: I like the use of the delegating wrapper class, except for the fact that it adds another three classes with specific knowledge of `A` and `B` just for this purpose, which is kind of sloppy. Given the scenario, I think that's pretty much the best available solution (other than stuff in Java 8, but chances are you're not using that...)

Comment: Yes, you could use method references, closures or reflection. The references should be fast, closures should be OK, reflection will be pretty slow.

Comment: Extending S with a midClass was my initial idea. In general I think there is no possibility for any elegant solution in any case. Thanks for the handful of possibilities. @ShotgunNinja chances were correct, no java8 :-/

Answer (score 3):

As far as i understand your situation is the following ?

```
public class S {
}

public class A extends S {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("A is doing something ...");
    }
}

public class B extends S {

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("B is doing something ...");
    }
}
```

actually i think this design is rather bad. if you have a chance to
clean this up you should do this. if this is not an option the following
workaround is possible ... introduce an interface declaring the common API
and wrap your instances using this interface ...

```
public interface WrapperInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

then you might use this like so

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WrapperInterface a=wrap(new A());
        WrapperInterface b=wrap(new B());

        a.doSomething();
        b.doSomething();
    }

    private static WrapperInterface wrap(final S s) {
        WrapperInterface downcast_field=null;
        if (s instanceof A)
            downcast_field = new WrapperInterface() {
                @Override
                public void doSomething() {
                    ((A) s).doSomething();
                }
            };
        else if (s instanceof B) {
            downcast_field = new WrapperInterface() {
                @Override
                public void doSomething() {
                    ((B) s).doSomething();
                }
            };
        }
        return downcast_field;
    }
}
```